# Is there a keyboard shortcut in the Windows version Adobe Lightroom for "Edit Metadata"?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-lightroom

I'd like to be able to click the first picture, <-edit metadata command->, type keywords, arrow key to next photo... rinse repeat.

However, I can't surmise the keyboard shortcut for 'edit metadata'.

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3628/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full Q&A can be found on the new [Photo & Editing](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3628/21) site.

The quick answer is **Ctrl+K**.